# non-negative continuous function where a sum of sample values diverges but integral converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Does there exist a non-negative continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ which has a convergent integral:

$$ \int_0^\infty f \, dx < \infty \tag{1}$$

with the restriction that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}_+, f(x) <1$. But, which has a strictly increasing sequence $ \{q_n\}_{n=0}^\infty \subset \mathbb{R}_+$ such that:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(q_n)=\infty \tag{2}$$

**Note:** My motivation for asking this question comes from probability, the Borel-Cantelli theorem in particular.

Comment: How about $f(x) = e^{-x}$ and $q_n = 1$ for every value of $n$? $\qquad$

Comment: Start with the function which is constant 0, add a "triangle" to the graph with height 1 and base 1, then after that add a second with the same height and base 1/2, keep doing that halving the base at each step, the integral will converge even though the function is continuous and takes value 1 at countably many points

Comment: That sum is not a Riemann sum, you haven't done any meshing or anything to mutliply the function values.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry. I implicitly assumed that $q_n$ was strictly increasing.

Comment: @AdamHughes I am welcome to corrections but I couldn't think of a better word.

Comment: Anyway the question in the title and the one in the body of the question are different, my earlier comment adresses the one in the body

Comment: @AidanRocke : So how about $q_n = 1 - 1/2^n\text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's a really nice example.

Comment: It seems to me that the indicator function of $\Bbb N$ with $q_n = n \ (\forall n)$ is such an example. I mean $m(\Bbb N) = 0$, so $\int_0^{\infty} \chi_{\Bbb N} = 0$. I don't know why the previous answer was deleted.

Comment: Because that's not continuous @Open Ball

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti wow, I wonder how I missed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with the function $f(x)=0$  $\forall x\in\mathbb R$, then add a "triangle" to the graph with height $1$ and basis $1/2$ centered around $x=1$, repeat this process adding a triangle with height $1$ and basis $2^{-n}$, centered around $n$ for each positive integer $n$.

The integral will be $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$ which converges.

But $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f(n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 1=\infty$.

Of course you can take triangles of lower height if you want $f(x)<1$

If you want to strengthen your conditions such a function can be made $C^\infty$ too via bump functions

Edit: actually your question is more similar to asking wether if a continuous positive function has a convergent integral then $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=0$, which is false, as I've shown above, but it's true if you assume $f$ uniformly continuous instead

Answer (score 3):

The comments have shown the flaw in the statement, but it looks like ideally you want $q_n=n$ or something similar. That's still possible. You construct $f$ to be zero outside of $(n-1/n^2,n+1/n^2)$, and on those intervals a triangle (i.e., $f(n)=1/2$, linear on the rest of the interval). Then $f(n)=1/2$ for all $n$, and 
$$
\int_0^\infty f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n^2}<\infty.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The question as NOW phrased is this:

> Does there exist a non-negative continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ which has a convergent integral: $$ \int_0^\infty f \, dx < \infty \tag{1}$$ with the restriction that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}_+, f(x) <1$. But, which has a strictly increasing sequence $ \{q_n\}_{n=0}^\infty \subset \mathbb{R}_+$ such that: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(q_n)=\infty \tag{2}$$

Certainly $q_n = 1 - \dfrac 1 {2^n}$ satisfies those requirements.

I'm *guessing* maybe you wanted $q_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ although you didn't say so.  Taking $\mathbb R_+$ to exclude $0$, how about this:
\begin{align}
q_n & = n \\[10pt]
f(x) & = e^{-x} + g(x) \\[10pt]
\end{align}
where $g(x)=0$ when $x$ is remote from all integers and $g(x)=1$ when $x$ is an integer, and $g(x)$ is nonzero near an integer $n$ only within a distance $2^{-n}$ from $n$. That way the integral of $g(x)$ over an interval centered at $n$ is $\le 2^{-n}$ but $f(q_n)=1$.

Comment: This is a really nice example. Regarding your guess, I just added my motivation for asking this question. It has to do with the Borel-Cantelli theorem.

Comment: @AidanRocke : I'm glad you liked it.